# RST Inline markup broken on some lines

Tags: restructuredtext

Inline markup is working for some strings, not for others:

```
**Traffic protection rule** created for ​``example.com``

Data is aggregated for ​``example.com``, ``​anysubdomain.example.com`` and ``onemorelevel.anysubdomain.example.com`` and then the rule is applied on the aggregated data.
```

[image: Inline markup working selectively]

In the first paragraph and in the second, example.com is not converted.

Comment: Confirmed. This appears to be a bug. Please [submit an issue with Sphinx](https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/issues). Include your version, reST sample, and how to reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) immediately before each of the two instances of ​

```
``example.com``
```

If you remove these two characters, the rendered output will be OK.

Zero-width space is not classified as a whitespace character in Unicode (see https://sourceforge.net/p/docutils/bugs/307/#ff33).

Comment: Thx mzjn, indeed a hidden character. This is migration from PDF into an online help center, and my editor doesn't show the zero-space chars!